# Is REISUB/REISUO to switch off/reboot safe?

Tags: grub, shutdown, reboot, zorin

I can't happen to find a fix to shutdown or reboot my Zorin OS 16.1. So far I have been using [REISUB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_SysRq_key#Uses) or REISUO as a quick fix. I was wondering if it can cause harm to my laptop in the longrun if I keep using this method.

For what it's worth :

```
vim /etc/default/grub

GRUB_DEFAULT=0
GRUB_TIMEOUT_STYLE=hidden
GRUB_TIMEOUT=0
GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=""
```

If needed I can share more details, just unsure what is needed.

Comment: I would first try to fix the actual problem. Try asking a new question, tell us how you try to shutdown, and what happens when you do.

Comment: Will do thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Physically there's no harm. In terms of data safety - you may find some files (specially databases) corrupted or empty on next boot.